# Zsh tab-completion not working

Tags: shell, autocomplete, zsh

Although I've used Oh-My-Zsh in the past, I decided this time around (i.e. setting up a new computer) I'd try to avoid installing it to keep things a bit leaner. Right now I'm trying to cherry-pick Oh-My-Zsh's insensitive tab-completion feature. Digging around its source repo, I found the following line:

`zstyle ':completion:*' matcher-list 'm:{a-zA-Z}={A-Za-z}' 'r:|=*' 'l:|=* r:|=*'`

I'm fairly confident this is the line Oh-My-Zsh executes to do what I want, so I tried adding it to my `.zshrc`. Restarted my terminal. Typed `cd desk`, then hit [tab]. No dice -- I didn't get `cd Desktop/`.

Here's the entire `.zshrc` for reference:

```
# pure shell theme
autoload -U promptinit; promptinit
prompt pure

# completion definitions
zstyle ':completion:*' matcher-list 'm:{a-zA-Z}={A-Za-z}' 'r:|=*' 'l:|=* r:|=*'
fpath=(/usr/local/share/zsh-completions $fpath)

# syntax highlighting (must be last line)
source /usr/local/share/zsh-syntax-highlighting/zsh-syntax-highlighting.zsh
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Look at this link, it solved for me: https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/issues/5651

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Just had to autoload and run `compinit`.

Here's the new `.zshrc`:

```
autoload -U compinit promptinit

promptinit
prompt pure

compinit
zstyle ':completion:*' matcher-list 'm:{a-zA-Z}={A-Za-z}' 'r:|=*' 'l:|=* r:|=*'
fpath=(/usr/local/share/zsh-completions $fpath)

source /usr/local/share/zsh-syntax-highlighting/zsh-syntax-highlighting.zsh
```

Comment: Hello, after switching from Bash to Zsh on macOS Catalina, Tab completion stopped working for me. Apparently it is working in directories where git is initiated, but not outside. What can I do?

Comment: @SEJU Try the command: `rehash` _(From [zsh guide](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Guide/zshguide03.html): The way commands are stored has other consequences. In particular, zsh won't look for a new command if it already knows where to find one. If I put a new ls command in /usr/local/bin in the above example, zsh would continue to use /bin/ls (assuming it had already been found). To fix this, there is the command rehash, which actually empties the command hash table, so that finding commands starts again from scratch.)_

Comment: @Jim has the correct answer here (at least for me)